# airodump-ng mon0 device

Tags: wifi, wireless, aircrack-ng

My laptop is in monitoring mode. I need to get the details of a client that makes probes and not include other bssid and their station.

I run `sudo airodump-ng -w s3 --bssid 74:de:2b:45:ed:d4 mon0`
The MAC is my wlan0, but it won't show any client IPs.

If run the command  `sudo airodump-ng -w s3 mon0` the s3.csv file shows the all IPs not associated to any of the AP. My requirement is to get the client that probes my mon0.

Comment: are you using two wifi cards? im pretty sure you cannot broadcast AND scan on one card?

Answer (score 1):

You should start by setting up your WIFI card to monitor mode on the right channel (it will help airodump-ng find the packets):

`airmon-ng start <interface> <AP channel>`

After that, the command that you are using is indeed the correct one. I mean, you are using the AP MAC address, right? You can use the **-a** parameter, it will display only associated clients.

`airodump-ng -c <AP channel> -a --bssid <AP MAC> -w <capture_file> <interface>`